# How to display the shadow of Material-style in Android native UI in Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, user-interface, material-design, shadow

In my case, I had an aar file in Unity that open Android's native Material-style UI.
But UI looks different.

In Android Studio Native UI Pircure
[Android Studio Native UI Pircure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMZpt.png)

In Unity Android Platform UI Pircure
[Unity Android Platform UI Pircure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdHL0.png)

Why does the button shadow of the native interface displayed by Unity is disappear?

Comment: Can you make it clear which asset you're using that allows you to add material design UI elements?

Comment: @purchaseTest I always use the element of "com.google.android.material" in layout